# How would you say "Free Spirit" in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation

While I believe there may have not been a term of "Free Spirit" in Latin, if we were to translate it and retain its English meaning using Latin words, what would it be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would translate that as ***animus liber***.
I think *liber* (free, unrestrained, not subordinate to anything) and *animus* (soul, mind, will, consciousness, intellect, rationality) match what "free spirit" means.
To get a better feeling of these two Latin words, I suggest taking a look at [any online Latin dictionary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79).

Calling a person an *animus* in Latin seems analogous to calling a person a "spirit" in English.
It is the same kind of metonymy, and works well in my opinion.
This is not an attested classical idiom as far as I know, but should be easily understandable to the Romans in a suitable context.

Comment: "Free spirit" in English is usually applied to people directly, as in "he is a free spirit". Is it idiomatic to use *animus* like that?

Comment: @Draconis Then I parsed the English correctly. In an expression like this I see no problem in calling a person an *animus* by metonymy, akin to calling a person a spirit in English. I don't find "spirit" idiomatic for a person directly (but I may be wrong!), but it works well in some phrases.

Answer (score 3):

The English “free spirit” is  a bahuvrihi compound meaning “whose spirit is free; having a free spirit”, of the same structure as Latin magnanimus “whose spirit is great”. The German equivalent of “free spirit” is “Freigeist” – patently a compound – which Grimm & Grimm & alii, “Deutsches Wörterbuch”, gloss as “liberioris judicii in rebus divinis”. I think “liberi judicii” works quite well for “free spirit”.

https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/freigeist

Answer (score 3):

*Animus* is perfectly appropriate in this context but I think that, rather than *liber*, either *effrenatus* or *effusus* would better express the idea of a spirit that is 'free' here.

The two adjectives are very close in meaning. *Effrenatus*, 'unbridled'  means 'lacking (external) control', while *effusus* indicates that the spirit enjoys an extraordinary freedom of expression.

Comment: I tend to see *effrenatus* (perhaps under the influence of *Catiline I*) as unambiguously pejorative, whereas "free spirit" in English is generally pretty positive. *Effusus* might capture that better, though.

Comment: @brianpck How do you define 'free spirit' in English, which is what we're after here? I'd say , with a highly individual lifestyle, attitude, or imagination ; if you like, a nonconformist, maybe a hippie, maverick, or radical. Someone who doesn't feel bound or restrained by convention. You could read either as pejorative according to context, or your point of view, but not at all exclusively so. It seems to me that _effrenata mens_ might in fact  even improve on _effrenatus animus_, if the subject was an enraptured flower-child or hippie. Would that be pejorative?